# nodejs express session is undefined when posting from ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, session

I've read and tried all the previous questions on the topic before posting here.
I have many pages all of which work, in the same manner(sessions are saved)
But i have this one page where it isn't and i can't figure out why...

I have this function:

```
function saveuser(){     
     uId = $('#userId').val();
     f = $('#firstName').val();
     l = $('#lastName').val();
     u = $('#firstname').val();
     p = $('#password').val();
     e = $('#email').val();
     ph = $('#phone').val();
     usernamee = $('#username').val();

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"/registerp",
                data:{
                   userId:uId,
                   firstName:f,
                   lastName:l,
                   password:p,
                   phone:ph,
                   email:e,
                   username:usernamee
                },
                success:function(data){
                   if(data.success){
                    showNotification({
                        message: "Profile saved successfully.",
                        autoClose: true,
                        type: "success",
                        duration: 3
                    });   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    showNotification({
                        message: "Failed to save profile.",
                        autoClose: true,
                        type: "error",
                        duration: 3
                    });   
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

All the info i'm retracting was also put on the page from the `session`.
When i call this `POST` the `req.session` is reset to nothing and all the data vanishes.

```
httponly=false
```

other pages work fine and some of them have similar functionality,
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What are your session middleware settings? Is the client-side XHR cross-origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it.
I knew that a session isn't saved unless the server returns something to the client.

Well, i used a redirect to another page on the same POST.
I thought the redirect is a type of GET for the client and that was my mistake.
I solved it by returning some random item

res.send({success:true});to that AJAX function and added that if the success = true in the javascript then i perform a GET call from the same operation.

That solved it.